# Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class com.example.app.ReferralApiModel]

Tags: java, android, json, rest, retrofit

I'm trying to fetch JSON data from my website throw REST API with retrofit2.
But when I run the app this error message show:

**Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class com.example.app.ReferralApiModel]**

I'm using retrofit library.

This is my code for the retrofit call:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConfig.URL)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(defaultHttpClient)
                .build();

        ReferralsPlaceHolderApi placeHolderApi = retrofit.create(ReferralsPlaceHolderApi.class);

        Call<List<Map<ReferralApiModel, String>>> call = placeHolderApi.getReferrals();
```

And this is my ReferralsPlaceHolderApi class:

```
public interface ReferralsPlaceHolderApi {

    @JsonDeserialize(keyAs = ReferralsCustomDeserializer.class)
    @GET(AppConfig.ENDPOINT_REFERRALS)
    Call<List<Map<ReferralApiModel, String>>> getReferrals();
}
```

Also this is my ReferralApiModel class:

```
public class ReferralApiModel {
    private String date;
    private String amount;
    private String currency;
    private String status;

    public ReferralApiModel() {}

    public ReferralApiModel(String date, String amount, String currency, String status) {
        this.date = date;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

This is the json data that I'm trying to get:

```
"[{\"id\":\"1\",\"refferal_wp_uid\":\"0\",\"campaign\":\"\",\"affiliate_id\":\"5\",\"visit_id\":\"1\",\"description\":\"\",\"source\":\"woo\",\"reference\":\"302\",\"reference_details\":\"68\",\"parent_referral_id\":\"0\",\"child_referral_id\":\"0\",\"amount\":\"1500.00\",\"currency\":\"\د\ج\",\"date\":\"2022-01-31 12:53:29\",\"status\":\"0\",\"payment\":\"0\",\"username\":\"aaa\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"refferal_wp_uid\":\"0\",\"campaign\":\"\",\"affiliate_id\":\"5\",\"visit_id\":\"2\",\"description\":\"\",\"source\":\"woo\",\"reference\":\"303\",\"reference_details\":\"68\",\"parent_referral_id\":\"0\",\"child_referral_id\":\"0\",\"amount\":\"1500.00\",\"currency\":\"\د\ج\",\"date\":\"2022-01-31 13:03:43\",\"status\":\"1\",\"payment\":\"0\",\"username\":\"aaa\"},{\"id\":\"3\",\"refferal_wp_uid\":\"0\",\"campaign\":\"\",\"affiliate_id\":\"5\",\"visit_id\":\"2\",\"description\":\"\",\"source\":\"woo\",\"reference\":\"304\",\"reference_details\":\"68\",\"parent_referral_id\":\"0\",\"child_referral_id\":\"0\",\"amount\":\"1500.00\",\"currency\":\"\د\ج\",\"date\":\"2022-01-31 13:04:33\",\"status\":\"2\",\"payment\":\"0\",\"username\":\"aaa\"}]"
```

Can anyone help me with this?.

Also I've found that this problem may be a class mapping problem, from this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16383752/8055951
If it's ?!, Can someone tell me how to map the ReferralsPlaceHolderApi class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson cannot deserialize custom classes as map keys. The key of your deserialized map is `ReferralApiModel`. I order to achieve it, you need to write your own `KeyDeserializer` and register it for your class with Jackson. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70812652/how-to-create-form-in-spring-mvc-that-allows-to-choose-item-from-menu-and-its-q/70813855#70813855) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246748/deserializing-non-string-map-keys-with-jackson) how to do that.

Also the json string in the question makes it look as if you **don't** need to deserialize into `List<Map<ReferralApiModel, String>>`, but into `List<ReferralApiModel>` instead. Which would make writing custom key deseriaslizers redundant.

**Edit:** Ok, receiving `json array`, which has been `json sting`-ified is just strange. It would be best, if someone on your team is responsible for this API and can fix it. If not, you have workarounds:

1. Parse twice with object mapper - first parse it to normal string, which would be `json array`, then parse this string into `List<YourObject>`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String string = mapper.readValue(initialJson, String.class);
List<ReferralApiModel> list = mapper.readValue(string, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, ReferralApiModel.class));
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

2. Turn it manually into proper json array. That means remove first and last char - double quote, and remove all those escapes - `\`. Something like this:

```
String jsonString = "the string";
jsonString = jsonString.substring(1, jsonString.length() - 1).replace("\\", "");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<ReferralApiModel> list = mapper.readValue(jsonString, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, ReferralApiModel.class));
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: When I'm using **List<ReferralApiModel>** instead of **List<Map<ReferralApiModel, String>>** this error message show **Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $**

Comment: @HamidAK The json string you posted **is** a  `List<ReferralApiModel>`. Or are you saying the response you are trying to deserialize actually starts/ends with the double quotes - `"`? That would mean you are receiving literary a `json string`, **not** a `json array` and explains the error you described.

Comment: Yeah actually it's starts/end with double quotes, any idea on how to handle this response?!

Comment: @HamidAK See edit.